# How to align text in the centre with an SVG element?

Tags: html, css, svg, adobe-xd

Hello to anyone out there that is capable of helping, I've ran into a bit of trouble that has had me doing a staring competition with VS Code for a while now haha.

I have designed a website UI in Adobe XD. In order to give my design some functionality I exported a few of the elements into an SVG format and moved over to HTML & CSS. I have a few SVG elements that have text labels inside them, which when designing I used Adobe XD to align the text centrally on the horizontal axis of the shapes. However, now I have added them to my HTML code, when it's viewed in a browser all the text has been pushed out to the left out my shape. It's done this for a few different elements but here's an example of one of them:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="172" height="239" viewBox="0 0 172 239">
  <g id="Boiler-fit-tag" transform="translate(-1499 -296)">
    <g id="Group_1" data-name="Group 1" transform="translate(1499 296)">
      <g id="Rectangle_28" data-name="Rectangle 28" fill="#fff" stroke="#090808" stroke-width="3">
        <rect width="172" height="239" rx="27" stroke="none"/>
        <rect x="1.5" y="1.5" width="169" height="236" rx="25.5" fill="none"/>
      </g>
      <line id="Line_1" data-name="Line 1" x2="143.142" transform="translate(14.579 143.583)" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="2"/>
    </g>
    <!--This line below is meant to be in the centre of the box but is running off the page to the left-->
    <text id="Boiler_Fitting" data-name="Boiler Fitting" transform="translate(1530 460)" fill="#e13413" font-size="20" font-family="FranklinGothic-Demi, Franklin Gothic" font-weight="300" letter-spacing="0.039em"><tspan x="-35.055" y="18">BOILER </tspan><tspan x="-36.344" y="40">FITTING</tspan></text>
    <g id="_002-boiler" data-name="002-boiler" transform="translate(1459.535 318.7)">
      <path id="Path_66" data-name="Path 66" d="M220.2,85.447A10.853,10.853,0,1,0,209.344,96.3,10.864,10.864,0,0,0,220.2,85.447Zm-18.868,0a8.015,8.015,0,1,1,8.015,8.014A8.024,8.024,0,0,1,201.329,85.447Z" transform="translate(-83.879 -60.484)"/>
      <path id="Path_67" data-name="Path 67" d="M253.158,112.1a1.42,1.42,0,0,0-2.006-2.006l-2.844,2.844c-1.27,1.27.707,3.306,2.006,2.006Z" transform="translate(-123.941 -88.929)"/>
      <path id="Path_68" data-name="Path 68" d="M155.886,9.51a6.47,6.47,0,0,0-4.62-6.18A93.317,93.317,0,0,0,125.464,0c-3.023,0-6.055.129-9.012.383a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,.243,2.827c2.876-.247,5.827-.372,8.769-.372a90.41,90.41,0,0,1,25,3.215,3.617,3.617,0,0,1,2.58,3.457V56.867H97.88V9.551a3.619,3.619,0,0,1,2.609-3.466c2.139-.613,4.457-1.155,6.889-1.613a1.42,1.42,0,0,0-.525-2.788c-2.518.473-4.922,1.037-7.145,1.674a6.469,6.469,0,0,0-4.665,6.194V71.545a6.47,6.47,0,0,0,4.62,6.18c1.072.314,2.448.682,4.107,1.056v3.458a4.582,4.582,0,0,0,3.288,4.414,52.87,52.87,0,0,0,6.367,1.451v7.328a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V88.517q1.273.158,2.677.28v6.636a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V88.984c1.175.055,2.4.087,3.687.087q1.858,0,3.687-.09v6.451a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V88.786q1.35-.119,2.677-.288v6.935a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V88.074q1.036-.178,2.055-.385a1.42,1.42,0,0,0-.57-2.779,65.153,65.153,0,0,1-31.115-.975,1.761,1.761,0,0,1-1.265-1.7V79.367a101.981,101.981,0,0,0,18.857,1.687,101.214,101.214,0,0,0,18.857-1.735v2.893a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V78.73c1.624-.366,2.988-.725,4.062-1.032a6.469,6.469,0,0,0,4.665-6.194V9.51Zm-5.447,65.459a92.431,92.431,0,0,1-24.975,3.248,90.41,90.41,0,0,1-25-3.215,3.617,3.617,0,0,1-2.58-3.457V59.7h55.168V71.5A3.619,3.619,0,0,1,150.439,74.969Z"/>
      <path id="Path_69" data-name="Path 69" d="M197.862,351.74a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,0,2.837A1.42,1.42,0,0,0,197.862,351.74Z" transform="translate(-82.259 -285.204)"/>
      <path id="Path_70" data-name="Path 70" d="M249.989,351.74a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,0,2.837A1.42,1.42,0,0,0,249.989,351.74Z" transform="translate(-124.525 -285.204)"/>
      <path id="Path_71" data-name="Path 71" d="M302.117,351.74a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,0,2.837A1.42,1.42,0,0,0,302.117,351.74Z" transform="translate(-166.792 -285.204)"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've looked online and have tried using the `text-anchor` and `dominant-baseline` tags but it didn't affect anything. I even tried changing the `x` and `y` values of the text field but for some of my SVGs that have text that runs over two lines using `<tspan>`, it's impossible to align them correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `text-anchor='middle'`.
- Set the `<text>` x position exactly to the center of the SVG (if the width is 172, set x="86").
- Move the `<text>` out of `<g>` elements with transforms.
- Make it the last child of `<svg>` to ensure it's not hidden by others.
- Set both `<tspan>` x="0"

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="172" height="239" viewBox="0 0 172 239">
  <g id="Boiler-fit-tag" transform="translate(-1499 -296)">
    <g id="Group_1" data-name="Group 1" transform="translate(1499 296)">
      <g id="Rectangle_28" data-name="Rectangle 28" fill="#fff" stroke="#090808" stroke-width="3">
        <rect width="172" height="239" rx="27" stroke="none"/>
        <rect x="1.5" y="1.5" width="169" height="236" rx="25.5" fill="none"/>
      </g>
      <line id="Line_1" data-name="Line 1" x2="143.142" transform="translate(14.579 143.583)" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="2"/>
    </g>
    <!--This line below is meant to be in the centre of the box but is running off the page to the left-->
    <g id="_002-boiler" data-name="002-boiler" transform="translate(1459.535 318.7)">
      <path id="Path_66" data-name="Path 66" d="M220.2,85.447A10.853,10.853,0,1,0,209.344,96.3,10.864,10.864,0,0,0,220.2,85.447Zm-18.868,0a8.015,8.015,0,1,1,8.015,8.014A8.024,8.024,0,0,1,201.329,85.447Z" transform="translate(-83.879 -60.484)"/>
      <path id="Path_67" data-name="Path 67" d="M253.158,112.1a1.42,1.42,0,0,0-2.006-2.006l-2.844,2.844c-1.27,1.27.707,3.306,2.006,2.006Z" transform="translate(-123.941 -88.929)"/>
      <path id="Path_68" data-name="Path 68" d="M155.886,9.51a6.47,6.47,0,0,0-4.62-6.18A93.317,93.317,0,0,0,125.464,0c-3.023,0-6.055.129-9.012.383a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,.243,2.827c2.876-.247,5.827-.372,8.769-.372a90.41,90.41,0,0,1,25,3.215,3.617,3.617,0,0,1,2.58,3.457V56.867H97.88V9.551a3.619,3.619,0,0,1,2.609-3.466c2.139-.613,4.457-1.155,6.889-1.613a1.42,1.42,0,0,0-.525-2.788c-2.518.473-4.922,1.037-7.145,1.674a6.469,6.469,0,0,0-4.665,6.194V71.545a6.47,6.47,0,0,0,4.62,6.18c1.072.314,2.448.682,4.107,1.056v3.458a4.582,4.582,0,0,0,3.288,4.414,52.87,52.87,0,0,0,6.367,1.451v7.328a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V88.517q1.273.158,2.677.28v6.636a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V88.984c1.175.055,2.4.087,3.687.087q1.858,0,3.687-.09v6.451a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V88.786q1.35-.119,2.677-.288v6.935a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V88.074q1.036-.178,2.055-.385a1.42,1.42,0,0,0-.57-2.779,65.153,65.153,0,0,1-31.115-.975,1.761,1.761,0,0,1-1.265-1.7V79.367a101.981,101.981,0,0,0,18.857,1.687,101.214,101.214,0,0,0,18.857-1.735v2.893a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,2.837,0V78.73c1.624-.366,2.988-.725,4.062-1.032a6.469,6.469,0,0,0,4.665-6.194V9.51Zm-5.447,65.459a92.431,92.431,0,0,1-24.975,3.248,90.41,90.41,0,0,1-25-3.215,3.617,3.617,0,0,1-2.58-3.457V59.7h55.168V71.5A3.619,3.619,0,0,1,150.439,74.969Z"/>
      <path id="Path_69" data-name="Path 69" d="M197.862,351.74a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,0,2.837A1.42,1.42,0,0,0,197.862,351.74Z" transform="translate(-82.259 -285.204)"/>
      <path id="Path_70" data-name="Path 70" d="M249.989,351.74a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,0,2.837A1.42,1.42,0,0,0,249.989,351.74Z" transform="translate(-124.525 -285.204)"/>
      <path id="Path_71" data-name="Path 71" d="M302.117,351.74a1.42,1.42,0,0,0,0,2.837A1.42,1.42,0,0,0,302.117,351.74Z" transform="translate(-166.792 -285.204)"/>
    </g>
  </g>
    <text id="Boiler_Fitting" text-anchor="middle" data-name="Boiler Fitting" transform="translate(86, 160)" fill="#e13413" font-size="20" font-family="FranklinGothic-Demi, Franklin Gothic" font-weight="300" letter-spacing="0.039em"><tspan y="18" x="0">BOILER</tspan><tspan y="40" x="0">FITTING</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's awesome, its worked for me thank you! I understand why you've changed the x in the `transform` tag to 86 but I don't understand why the y has gone from `transform="translate(1530 460)` to `transform="translate(86 160)` and not 230 for the y?

Comment: Because I have tried following the instructions for other SVG elements that use the exact same format. The width of my rectangle border is 172 still but for example another text inside has `transform="translate(1321 460)`. If i make this half the size, it instead moves it to the left  outside of the shape, rather than moving to the right to align centrally

Comment: @CadyOG, so it's OK now or there is still something that should be fixed?

Comment: It's okay now tbf, it was a bit fiddly last night to get it to try and align centre but because I knew which elements to change to affect the correct positioning i go there in the end thanks